# Explain why all attributes of a class are not ordinarily defined to be static

Tags: java

Could someone please explain why are attributes of a class are not ordinarily defined to be static.

Comment: Why do you want to define them as static. Static attributes mantain same value across all the objects, thats why attributes are not normally defined as static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a field is made static, it is associated with that **class**. It means that once initialized, every use of the field sees that same thing. Take a look:

```
class Test {
    public final static String test = "test";
}
```

This would be used as `Test.test`. You can think of it as a field of the `Class` object that is created on loading `Test`.

When you make a field non-static, that means it is associated with an **instance** of the class. So if you had this:

```
class Test {
    public String test = "test";
}
```

... you'd use it like so:

```
Test t = new Test();
System.out.println(t.test);
```

It could vary from instance to instance, for example if the `test` field is initialized through a constructor argument or altered via a method.

Answer (score 1):

because the purpose of most of the class is to have object of that class and to hold the state of that object we define non static fields.

Answer (score 1):

Since ordinarily you want to have several instances of a class.
Assume you have a class person, it its field name would be static all instances would have the name you assigend last.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone please explain why are attributes of a class are not ordinarily defined to be static.

Because that would make it harder to do O-O programming in Java.  Since Java is *designed* to be an O-O programming language, it makes no sense to make the O-O paradigm hard.

---

It seems to me that you think that non-static attributes are somehow a nuisance to you.  If that is the case, you've probably failed to appreciate the value / usefulness of O-O programming, and failed to understand the limitations and drawbacks of using static attributes.

I suggest that you read a good Java tutorial or a book on O-O programming with Java.

Answer (score 0):

Read this : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html and this : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html